# Vim paste error: "E353 nothing in register ""

Tags: vim, clipboard

I just installed [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) and got my Vim setup. I have run into a slight caveat and I am not sure why it is happening.

When I try to paste something with the middle mouse button, I get:

> E353 nothing in register "

However, if I **double click** the middle mouse button, the text gets pasted as expected. The first click makes the error show up, the second click gets it to paste after a delay of about a second.

Why is this happening, or how I can fix it?

This is my *~/.vimrc* file:

```
syntax enable

set nowrap
set mouse=a
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set number
set showcmd
set cursorline
set showmatch
set autoindent

"folding settings
set foldmethod=indent   "fold based on indent
set foldnestmax=10      "deepest fold is 10 levels
set nofoldenable        "don't fold by default
set foldlevel=1

set clipboard=unnamed  "share one clipboard for everything
set pastetoggle=<F3>
```

I have since run into other strange behavior, for example using // to search for regex doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Don't `:set paste`; this disables any mappings and causes weird things. Only do this directly before pasting from the terminal; see `:h 'pastetoggle'` how to set up a key for toggling this.

Comment: Thanks, still run into the same issue though

Comment: This error is [so common for Vim/vi beginners](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/08/arm-toolchain-ubuntu-19-04-black-magic-probe/#comment-66) (due to the infamous modes, command mode, insert mode, etc.) that there ought to be duplicate somewhere, either here or on another Stack Exchange site. Sample from Stack Overflow: *[Error “E353: Nothing in register” using 'vi' on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328536)*. Can someone find more candidates?

Comment: This issue can have multiple causes (your two links, for example) so one answer is definitely not enough.